# why regex doesn't match exactly with double words

Tags: php, regex

sometimes the string has single and double words it works well with single words but not with double becase of the space

```
$_POST['descricao'] = "UNITED STATES test";  
$_POST['descricao'] = preg_replace("/\b([A-Z]{2,})\b/", "<b>$1</b>", $_POST['descricao']);
```

output: `<b>UNITED</b> <b>STATES</b> teste`
and everytime that i send my form it gets formated again like `<b><b>UNITED</b></b> <b><b>STATES</b></b> test`

for the string `$str = "UNITED STATES test"` it should output: `<b>UNITED STATES test</b> instead of <b>UNITED</b> <b>STATES</b> test`

Comment: Could you clarify a little bit more: "For an input string of AAA, I wanted the output to be XX, but I am getting YY".

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: it's another case.. better a new question than talk by comments

Comment: Could it be that you need to test that the thing right before the uppercase word isn't already `<b>`? In other words - need a lookaround?

Comment: Not that confusing considering he shows the string, the regex he was trying to use, and the variation in the string that breaks his regex.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller, this is a separate question based off the original. I directed him to post a new question and not to ask more questions in comments or an answered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[A-Z]` character class doesn't include any spaces.  so add spaces if you need:

-- added the `\s`

```
$_POST['descricao'] = preg_replace("/\b([A-Z\s]{2,})\b/", "<b>$1</b>", $_POST['descricao']);
```

But that might match more than you need if you only want up to two words max do this:

--added the: `(\s[A-Z]{2,})?`

```
$_POST['descricao'] = preg_replace("/\b([A-Z]{2,}(\s[A-Z]{2,})?)\b/", "<b>$1</b>", $_POST['descricao']);
```

**As far as double `<b><b>` ... `</b></b>`**
There might be a way using look behinds and lookaheads if you really have to do it all in one line of code.  However, I would just do a quick and dirty preg_replace cleanup like so:

```
 $_POST['descricao'] = preg_replace('/<(\/)?b><(?:\/)?b>/', "<$1b>", $_POST['descricao']);
```

^^ that will remove any duplicates

Comment: it worked but is there any way to no formatting again after resend the form? like `<b><b>UNITED STATES</b></b> test`